# How do I get the lates tm.detail_notes ( tm.detail_notes for max(tm.timeslip_date))?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I have a query that return some record, but I need to get whatever the latest `tm.detail_notes` on `max(tm.timeslip_date)`. Right now I am getting an error. (I have multiple record dates on the table and each day have note)

Query

```
SELECT
      min(tm.create_date) 'Created Date'
    , max(tm.timeslip_date) 'Last Bill Date'
    , cases.case_sk
    , cases.case_number
    , cases.closed_ind
    , cases.atty2_sk
    , vc.atty2_name 'Business Leader'
    , em.smtp_reply_to 'Business Leader Email'
    , cases.atty1_sk
    , vc.atty1_name 'Assign Attorney'
    , tm.detail_notes
FROM dbo.cases
LEFT JOIN dbo.vcases vc ON cases.case_sk = vc.case_sk
LEFT JOIN dbo.employee em ON cases.atty2_sk = em.employee_sk    
LEFT JOIN dbo.timeslips tm ON cases.case_sk = tm.case_sk
WHERE 
      cases.case_number = '0130751-KMG' 
      AND tm.timeslip_date <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
      AND cases.closed_ind = 'O'
GROUP BY 
      cases.case_sk
    , cases.case_number
    , cases.closed_ind
    , cases.atty2_sk
    , vc.atty2_name 
    , em.smtp_reply_to 
    , cases.atty1_sk
    , vc.atty1_name
    , tm.detail_notes
```

Error

*The text, next, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.*

I would really appreciate any help on this. Lastly, can anyone confirmed my logic, I am trying to get cases with no `tm.timeslip_date`  for the last 90 days. I should get that with `tm.timeslip_date <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())` this logic, right.

Thank you so much

Comment: Please add some example data and expected results from that data in form of a text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: You really, REALLY, should not be using the text and image datatypes by now!

Comment: And your reference to tm.timeslip_date in the where clause logically turns your outer join to tm into an inner join. So maybe you should think about your goal and your join logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more `tm.detail_notes` appears to be a `text` column which is one of the special columns of large, open-ended data types. See [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). These fields cannot be used in [columns expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) of an aggregate query with `GROUP BY`.

To incorporate the `text` field with your aggregation, consider using two related CTEs for a unit level and aggregate level join. Final query will then bind the text column to aggregation joined at the `Last Bill Date`.

```
WITH unit AS (
   -- NO AGGREGATIONS
   SELECT
         tm.create_date 
       , tm.timeslip_date
       , cases.case_sk
       , cases.case_number
       , cases.closed_ind
       , cases.atty2_sk
       , vc.atty2_name    AS [Business Leader]
       , em.smtp_reply_to AS [Business Leader Email]
       , cases.atty1_sk
       , vc.atty1_name    AS [Assign Attorney]
       , tm.detail_notes
   FROM dbo.cases
   LEFT JOIN dbo.vcases vc ON cases.case_sk = vc.case_sk
   LEFT JOIN dbo.employee em ON cases.atty2_sk = em.employee_sk    
   LEFT JOIN dbo.timeslips tm 
         ON cases.case_sk = tm.case_sk
         AND tm.timeslip_date <= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()) -- MOVED FROM WHERE TO ON CLAUSE
   WHERE cases.case_number = '0130751-KMG'
     AND cases.closed_ind = 'O'
), agg AS (
   -- NO JOINS / WHERE
   SELECT
         MIN(u.create_date)   AS [Created Date]
       , MAX(u.timeslip_date) AS [Last Bill Date]
       , u.case_sk
       , u.case_number
       , u.closed_ind
       , u.atty2_sk
       , u.[Business Leader]
       , u.[Business Leader Email]
       , u.atty1_sk
       , u.[Assign Attorney]
   FROM unit u
   GROUP BY 
         u.case_sk
       , u.case_number
       , u.closed_ind
       , u.atty2_sk
       , u.[Business Leader]
       , u.[Business Leader Email]
       , u.atty1_sk
       , u.[Assign Attorney]
)

-- FINAL QUERY JOINING ON GROUP COLUMNS AND AGG DATES
SELECT agg.*, unit.detail_notes
FROM agg
INNER JOIN unit
   ON  agg.case_sk = unit.case_sk
   AND agg.case_number = unit.case_number
   AND agg.closed_ind = unit.closed_ind
   AND agg.atty2_sk = unit.atty2_sk
   AND agg.[Business Leader] = unit.[Business Leader]
   AND agg.[Business Leader Email] = unit.[Business Leader Email]
   AND agg.atty1_sk = unit.atty1_sk
   AND agg.[Assign Attorney] = unit.[Assign Attorney]  

   AND agg.[Created Date] = unit.[create_date]
   AND agg.[Last Bill Date] = unit.[timeslip_date]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This is kinda work but when I add `[Created Date]` on Inner JOIN at the end it will only give me 500 records. When I remove it, I will get 7000 records, but I get some duplicates.  I only inner join be keys. Otherwise it will run forever.  Any idea why is that or any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see any data. So only you can decide what is the right output. Why can't 500 records be the solution? Not clear what you mean by *keys*. Please advise if there are duplicate rows across *all* or some columns for the exact query in this answer which joins on grouping columns and aggregates (`Created Date` and `Last Bill Date`). To be clear, this answer returns the `LEFT JOIN` data at the minimum *create date* and *last bill date*. If these aggregates are not unique per each set of grouping columns, final result will show duplicates.